# Using a UIScrollView and UIViews to call an action when a view appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a long UIScrollView with multiple UIViews in it.  How do I grab an action/event (i.e. call a method) when the bottom of the scrollview is reached?

Answer (score 0):

you need to check scrollview delegate method and also set its delegate to listen its delegate methods.

> ```
> - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
>     float currentEndPoint = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
>     if (currentEndPoint >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
>         // end point reached
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by, setting up `UIScrollViewDelegate` for you `UIScrollView`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scrollview setDelegate:self];
    [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollview.frame.size.width, 900)];
}

#pragma mark - Scrollview Delegate 
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y+scrollView.frame.size.height==scrollView.contentSize.height) {
        NSLog(@"You are at bottom with contnet goes up :%f",scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    }
}
```

Hope this help you.